# How to Preform foreach in a IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, foreach, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable` list with multi value in it, and I want to `foreach` over its values. I have this code

```
IEnumerable<object> Place = db.Places.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Nam1 = x.Name1, Name2 = x.Name2);

foreach(dynamic thisPlace in Place) 
{
    Response.Write (thisPlace.Id)
    Response.Write (thisPlace.Name1)
    Response.Write (thisPlace.Name2)
}
```

This code work fine and after it's done, it throws an error:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Place_F6C785C74658C47ED4BFCF45D13FE7D754CCA2F688B6CBDD079244CE52B46291'."

Now the question is how to do `foreach` with `IEnumerable` the right way?

Comment: what is Trips here?

Comment: Its Wrong I will Modify it

Comment: You are better off with reading some c# book.
If you would use var instead of IEnumerable<object>. Then if you would use var as a loop variable instead of dynamic - everything would be fine.
Also you would want to .ToList() or .ToArray() your enumerable. It's a "best practice".

Comment: The error can't possibly come from the code you show. There isn't any entity object passing a serializer *unless* `Name1` or `Name2` are something else than string, as their names suggest.

Comment: @AlexanderTaran ... I understand the difference between  IEnumerable<object> and var ..... and I modified the code to fit , Thank you

Comment: @GertArnold ....  Yes it wasn't in that code block it was some where else and I solve it .... Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code wont get executed. Because you do not have property named **`Name1`** as you showed in the code.

Second, even if you have you should use **`var`** instead of using **`IEnumerable<object>`**

```
var Places = db.Places.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Nam1 = x.Name1, Name2 = x.Name2}).ToList();
foreach (var thisPlace in Places)
{
  Response.Write(thisPlace.Id)
  Response.Write(thisPlace.Name1)
  Response.Write(thisPlace.Name2)
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, why does this make a difference?

Comment: This code work fine as well as my code .... but as I said the error is after the code is done execution ... then I figure out the problem some where else and solve it , Thank you